# $l^{p}$ is not finite dimensional

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, vector-spaces, lp-spaces

Well, the exercise was to prove that $l^{p}$ is not finite dimensional space for $p$=2.

I did it proving that the unit ball is not compact. Easy.

However, i was trying to build an element $x \in l^{p}$ that given a finite basis $\lbrace e_{1}, ... ,e^{n} \rbrace$ cannot be obtained via finite linear combinations of elements of basis. Probably this is quite easy, but i couldnt. Can you help me ?

Thank you :)

Comment: You can't really build such an element because for any $x$, the set $\{x\}$ is linearly independent (and a basis of a 1-dimensional subspace). So this cannot be used to conclude the infinite dimension of the space.

Comment: This is true for all $\ell^p$ (assuming you mean as usual infinite sequences). Not only $p=2$.

Answer (score 8):

It's easy to write down an infinite set of linearly independent vectors. Just let $v_n$ be the sequence which has $1$ in the $n$th place and $0$ everywhere else.

Comment: Yeah, but i was trying, out of curiosity, to really build an example of an element that would never be a finite linear combination of elements of a finite basis.

Comment: @thetruth: that's nonsense. Any element v is in a one-element "basis" {v}.

Comment: well, that's true. i feel bad now :)

Comment: @thetruth Any element in any vector space with any basis is a finite linear combination of basis elements. Even if you fix some basis, it is impossible to form a vector that is an infinite linear combination of basis elements.